# In todo , When a task is edited, the changes are visible on the console and after refreshing the page, but they are not visible in tasks list

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
const TodoCard = ({ title, id, delid }) => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [Inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    title: "",
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    setInputs({ title });
  }, [title]);

  const change = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInputs({ ...Inputs, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
    console.log(title);
  };

  const handleUpdate = async () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
    await axios
      .put(`http://localhost:1000/api/v2/updateTask/${id}`, Inputs)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        toast.success("Task Added");
      });
    console.log(Inputs);
    console.log("title is  : ", title);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="task-cont">
        {isEditing ? (
          <input
            name="title"
            type="text"
            value={Inputs.title}
            onChange={change}
          />
        ) : (
          <div className="tasks">{title}</div>
        )}
        <div className="task-icons">
          {isEditing ? (
            <ImCheckmark className="icons" onClick={handleUpdate} />
          ) : (
            <>
              <MdDelete className="icons" onClick={() => delid(id)} />
              <MdModeEditOutline
                className="icons"
                onClick={handleEdit}
                name="title"
              />
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default TodoCard;
```

I would like to view the edited tasks in the input field. Currently, they only appear after a page refresh, but I want them to update immediately. There seems to be an issue with state management in React. The inputs are updated, but the title is not updating without a refresh.

In the TodoCard component, the useState hook is used to manage the state of whether the task is being edited (isEditing) and the input value (Inputs). The useEffect hook is used to update the input value when the title prop changes.

The handleEdit function sets the isEditing state to true, which switches the component to edit mode. The handleUpdate function sends a PUT request to update the task on the server and sets the isEditing state to false, which switches the component back to view mode.

Comment: Hi! What do you mean "when the title prop changes"? you can't change a prop from within a component. Also, you said it shows in the console? What line triggers this logging to console?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you want to happen, but if it is just to see the changes on the console whenever the state changes, simply use a useEffect to log the `Inputs` as they change: ```useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Inputs : ', Inputs);
  }, [Inputs]);```

Comment: After the PUT request where is your code updating the client-side state?

Comment: Yes , after the put req it is change on the database as well . But the updated task is not seeing in the page until it refreshes .

Answer (score 0):

Let me start out by explaining some fundamentals of state management in react.
A user sees changes when one of two things happens, when props change, or when state changes.
This is due to a process in react known as re-rendering.
Basically re-rendering is your browser running that components code again, so that it can update the DOM.
When an elements' internal state changes(like when you made changes to Inputs) react only re-renders that element.
If that element however, is one that simply renders props passed to it by its parent component, and not its own internal state, then in order to update the DOM, you need to update the props being passed to it. 
This is the common pattern:

1. An App has top level "global" state that it may get from some backend.
2. The app passes this state, via props or context to elements that need it.
3. Some of these elements sometimes directly render this prop they have received, just like you rendered `title`
4. If the user is to interact with an element and give it cause to update a value it receives as a prop, it cannot directly modify a prop as in react, data flows top down.
5. The parent element must therefore provide its children that it wants to grant permission to update state, a function that allows them access to the `setState` function tied to the global state.
6. When they(child components) update this state, they cause the parent to re-render, and the new state value passed to the children as a prop.
7. The component can then use this value.

I have updated your code to follow this pattern. I however had to take out the api.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';



const TodoCard = ({ title, id, delid, update }) => {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [titleState, setTitleState] = useState(title);
  const [Inputs, setInputs] = useState({
    title: "",
  });

  const change = (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setInputs({ ...Inputs, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleEdit = () => {
    setIsEditing(true);
  };

  const handleUpdate = () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
   update(id, Inputs.title);
    setTitleState(Inputs.title);
    console.log(Inputs);
    console.log("title is  : ", title);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="task-cont">
        {isEditing ? (
          <input
            name="title"
            type="text"
            value={Inputs.title}
            onChange={change}
          />
        ) : (
          <div className="tasks">{title}</div>
        )}
        <div className="task-icons">
          {isEditing ? (
            <button className="icons" onClick={handleUpdate} > DONE </button>
          ) : (
            <>
              
              <button
                className="icons"
                onClick={handleEdit}
                name="title">
                EDIT
              </button>
            </>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default function App(props) {
  const [list, setList] = useState([{ id: 1, delid: 2, title: "f"}, { id: 2, delid: 3, title: "r"}, { id: 4, delid: 5, title: "e"}]);

const updateList = (editId, newValue) =>  {
const newList = list.map(item => editId === item.id ? ({...item,title: newValue }): item)
  setList(newList);
};
  return (
    <div className='App'>
   {
    list.map(item => 
    <TodoCard title ={item.title} id = {item.id} delid = {item.id} update={updateList} />
    )
   }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions. Hope this helps!